# Show the parceled string array list in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am passing an array list containing values to another activity
The passed array list contains the values as :

```
          "Details": [
            {
                "ID": 1,
                "Name": "ABC",
                 "Supervisor": [
                    {
                        "supervisorID": 1,
                        "Name": "XYZ"
                     }
                 ]
             }
           ]
```

I want to get the supervisor details from it and show it in recycler view How will i achieve  this

```
       ArrayList<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) 
       getIntent().getSerializableExtra("site");

       mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
       mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
       mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
       mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, 
          LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
       mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

Comment: Follow this guide https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

create model class with variable names as your demand and show me the function which is fetching response 
where you can use JSON object and string key for parsing
like this

```
try {
        // get JSONObject from JSON file
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
        // fetch JSONObject named employee
        JSONObject employee = obj.getJSONObject("employee");
        // get employee name and salary
        name = employee.getString("name");
        salary = employee.getString("salary");
        // set employee name and salary in TextView's
        employeeName.setText("Name: "+name);
        employeeSalary.setText("Salary: "+salary);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this complete code

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
// ArrayList for person names, email Id's and mobile numbers
ArrayList<String> personNames = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> emailIds = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> mobileNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // get the reference of RecyclerView
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    // set a LinearLayoutManager with default vertical orientation
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    try {
        // get JSONObject from JSON file
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        // fetch JSONArray named users
        JSONArray userArray = obj.getJSONArray("users");
        // implement for loop for getting users list data
        for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length(); i++) {
            // create a JSONObject for fetching single user data
            JSONObject userDetail = userArray.getJSONObject(i);
            // fetch email and name and store it in arraylist
            personNames.add(userDetail.getString("name"));
            emailIds.add(userDetail.getString("email"));
            // create a object for getting contact data from JSONObject
            JSONObject contact = userDetail.getJSONObject("contact");
            // fetch mobile number and store it in arraylist
            mobileNumbers.add(contact.getString("mobile"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //  call the constructor of CustomAdapter to send the reference and data to Adapter
    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, personNames, emailIds, mobileNumbers);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter); // set the Adapter to RecyclerView
}

public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("users_list.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

}